# Rotational wave funtion of a nucleus

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, nuclear-physics

The rotational hamiltonian of an axially symmetric rotor is, in the intrinsic frame of the body, where the moment of inertia is diagonal, 
$$\mathcal{H} = \frac{\hslash^2}{2I} \left(J^2 - I_3^2\right) +\frac{\hslash^2}{2I_3} I_3^2$$
Classically, the state of this object is given by the three Euler angles. Quantum mechanically, the state is given by (Wong, S., "Introductory Nuclear Physics") the quantum numbers $J$, $M_J$ (third component of $\vec{J}$ in the lab frame) and $K$ (3rd component of $\vec{J}$ in the body intrinsic frame). Then the wave function is the following combination of $\mathcal{D}$ functions as functions of the three Euler angles:
$$\psi_{JMK}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) = \sqrt{\frac{2J+1}{16\pi^2(1+\delta_{k0})}} \left( \mathcal{D}^J_{MK}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) \pm (-1)^{J+K} \mathcal{D}^J_{M-K}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) \right)$$

**My question is, why can $M_J$ and $K$ be at the same time good quantum numbers since $ J_3$ doesn't commute in general with the rotated operator** $I_3 = e^{i\vec{\alpha}\vec{J}} J_z e^{-i\vec{\alpha}\vec{J}}$?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that $I_3$ is the angular momentum J projected on an axis obtained from the axis z rotated by α?

Comment: Yes, $I_3$ is the component of the angular momentum along the symmetry axis of the body. $e^{\vec{\alpha}\cdot \vec{J}}$ is a general rotation. In the books is written in terms of the three Euler angles as $R = e^{-i\alpha J_z}e^{-i\beta J_x} e^{-i\gamma J_z}$